# `retry` doesn't evaluate begin block again

Tags: ruby

I have a code like:

```
i = 0
begin
  p "5 times"
rescue
  i += 1
  retry if i < 5
end
```

I thought with this code the begin block evaluated 5 times, but the text is output only once.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `ruby 2.1.2p95`.

Comment: 5.times{puts "5 times"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would execute 5 times if an error had been raised, which is not the case.

Try this

```
i = 0
begin
  p "5 times"
  raise "error"
rescue
  i += 1
  retry if i < 5
end
```

If you want code to be executed even when there are no exceptions use `ensure`, but you can't `retry` from there.

```
i = 0
begin
  p "5 times"
rescue
  # won't run if there are no exceptions
  i += 1
  retry if i < 5
ensure
  # always runs
end
```

Answer (score 2):

#### No exception is raised, so the "rescue" block is never called.

Try this instead (note the line with `raise`):

```ruby
i = 0
begin
  p "5 times"
  raise "...transfer control to the 'rescue' block..."
rescue
  i += 1
  retry if i < 5
end
```